# Data transformation Using Proc Transpose or simpler procedures

Tags: sql, sas

I have a data set:

```
Period    Store   Item    feature_1       feature_2
 JAN        A      a1        3               4
 JAN        A      a2        4               9
 JAN        A      a3        2               1
 JAN        A      a4        4               9
 FEB        A      a2        4               9
 JAN        B      a2        3               1
 FEB        B      b2        4               9 
.....
```

I would like to get the dataset:

```
 Period    Store   a1_feature_1    a1_feature_2      a2_feature_1      a2_feature_2....
 JAN        A         3               4                   4                9
 FEB        A         .               .                   4                9
 JAN        B         .               .                   3                1
```

where the final data set have each observation containing each outlet during each period, while having all the features for each item together in the same observation.

My initial guess is to attempt using first a macro to create the variables a1_feature_1, a1_feature_2, a2_feature_1, a2_feature_2....

and then use a proc sql group by to collapse across the Store and period.

I am wondering if this can be done using proc transpose, sql, or would there be any other simpler steps to transforming this data?

Comment: One way of doing this would be to transpose both features separately and then merging the resulting tables using item as id and feature_1 resp feature_2 as suffix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing this:

```
data have;
input (Period  Store Item) ($) feature_1 feature_2; cards;
  JAN        A      a1        3               4
  JAN        A      a2        4               9
  JAN        A      a3        2               1
  JAN        A      a4        4               9
  FEB        A      a2        4               9
  JAN        B      a2        3               1
  FEB        B      b2        4               9
;
run;

proc sql noprint;
select distinct cats(item,'_feature1'),cats(item,'_feature2'),
into :item_list1 separated by ' ', :item_list2 separated by ' '
from have;
quit;

data want;
  do until(last.period);
    set have;
    by store period notsorted;
    array f1[*] &item_list1;
    array f2[*] &item_list2;
    do i = 1 to dim(f1);
      if vname(f1[i]) eq: trim(item) then do;
        f1[i] = feature_1;
        f2[i] = feature_2;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  drop i feature_1 feature_2;
run;
```

N.B. this does not give you the column order shown in the question, but you could easily fix that with a bit of additional logic if you wanted. Also, the macro variables used to define the arrays will only hold enough variable names for a few thousand items.

Answer (score 0):

You can also put all your `feature_` variables into a list, transpose the data using each one and name the suffix, then merge together. With this method you DO NOT have to manually type out all your `feature_` variables as the `sql` method does it for you:

```
data test;
length Period    Store   Item    $5 feature_1       feature_2 8;
input Period $ Store $ Item $ feature_1 feature_2;
datalines;
 JAN        A      a1        3               4
 JAN        A      a2        4               9
 JAN        A      a3        2               1
 JAN        A      a4        4               9
 FEB        A      a2        4               9
 JAN        B      a2        3               1
 FEB        B      b2        4               9 
 ;
run;

proc sort data = test;
    by PERIOD STORE;
run;

** how many feature_ vars do I have? **;
proc sql noprint;
    create table features as
    select NAME 
    from dictionary.columns
    where libname="WORK" and memname="TEST" and index(NAME,"feature");

    ** put them into a list to loop over **;
    select NAME 
    into: feature_list separated by " "
    from features;
quit;

%put &feature_list.;

** transpose data using each feature_ variable then merge when finished **;
%MACRO loop_over(feature_list);
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&feature_list.));
    %let feature=%scan(&feature_list.,&i.);
    proc transpose data = test out=trans_&feature.(drop=_NAME_) SUFFIX=_&feature.;
        by PERIOD STORE;
        id ITEM;
        var &feature.;
    run;
%end;

data merged;
    merge trans_:;
    by PERIOD STORE;
run;
%MEND;

%loop_over(&feature_list.);
```

Comment: This works, but it will perform horribly for larger datasets compared to the array approach, due to the number of proc transpose calls, each of which has to read the whole dataset twice.